# Asterisk: SIP Transfer (Refer) - Changing Headers / Caller ID of Original Caller

Tags: php, asterisk, asteriskami, agi

Basically I have been implementing a standard TRANSFER via PHP AGI (PAGI) to one of our internal PBX systems from Asterisks.

The caller calls into our Asterisk application, we then do some searching and we change the caller id which works perfectly fine. However if we then transfer the call to our PBX it does not retain the caller id, it instead uses the original caller ID.

To ensure we do not strain asterisk, we wish to transfer the call (ie refer) rather an issue a DIAL to our other PBX so that the Asterisk becomes removed from the interaction with the caller and the internal PBX.

I have tried the following:

```
$this->agi->exec('SET', array("CONNECTEDLINE(number,i)=".$this->customer->OutboundID));
$this->agi->exec('SET', array("CONNECTEDLINE(name,i)=".$this->customer->OutboundID));
$this->agi->exec('SET', array("CONNECTEDLINE(pres,i)=".$this->customer->OutboundID));
$this->agi->exec('SET', array("ORIG_CID=".$this->customer->OutboundID));
$this->agi->exec('SET', array("CALLERID(num)=".$this->customer->OutboundID));
```

Kind Regards

Warren

Comment: So you are changing Caller-ID on Asterisk, then you dropping Asterisk from chain and expect that Caller-ID will stay somehow magically changed?

Comment: In essence yes! The idea is to change the FROM header of the original caller so that once its forwarded on it maintains the modified FROM.

Caller calls into Asterisk with CLI as 0800 085 965
We then modify this request to show 123456
Our internal PBX should see the call coming in from 123456 however it shows the 0800 number

Thanks for your prompt response!

Comment: Using REFER to Achieve Call Transfer

   A REFER [RFC3515] can be issued by the Transferor to cause the
   Transferee to issue an INVITE to the Transfer Target.  Note that a
   successful REFER transaction does not terminate the session between
   the Transferor and the Transferee.  If those parties wish to
   terminate their session, they must do so with a subsequent BYE
   request. 

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5589#section-5

This means that you trigger callee to start transfer. This means if Callee have CallerID 1111, then why it should be 2222?